# how to transform movieclip shape?

Tags: flash, actionscript, movieclip

hey there. I was wondering if there any way to change movieclip shape, when it on stage by as2. thx for helping

Comment: Do you want to transform the clip(position/rotation/scale/skew) or do you want to 'morph' it ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a **shape tween** - but in terms of using ActionScript to change a shape you'll either need to create a MovieClip that contains different shapes and just use `gotoAndStop()` to select which shape you want to display, or restrict yourself to these properties which change the dimensions and that's about it:

```
mc._width
mc._height
mc._xscale
mc._yscale
```

Also

```
mc._rotation
```

You could look into way more complex features for **skewing** shapes and such.. I'm not sure if AS2 has these features but in ActionScript 3 it would be the **Matrix** class:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/geom/Matrix.html

Comment: I meant that I want to change the movieclip's (which is on stage) shape into other movieclip's shape which i have in the library.